# What is a word for a person who has been initiated into secret knowledge (apprentice, ___, master)?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

I'm looking for a noun that can fit well in a 3-level scale: *apprentice, ____, master.*

The scale describes the progress of a person from a layman/uninitiated (*apprentice*), through being accomplished and versed in the secret knowledge he acquired, and finally arriving at the ability to teach and mentor apprentices into the same knowledge (*master*).

The noun *initiate* has connotations of being a beginner and thus isn't good for my need.

Answer (score 40):

[*Journeyman*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Journeyman) would feel like the most natural choice to me.

(Addendum: Freemasonry goes with [*fellow craft*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freemasonry#Degrees) between *entered apprentice* and *master mason*, but that's a bit wordy for my tastes.)

Comment: indeed, it is THE choice for the series in the example given.

Comment: Apprentice, journeyman, master being the traditional guild membership progression, yeah.  It has behavioral implications that may be unfortunate for a non-professionally-oriented secret society, though (that the journeyman should be *journeying*, looking for a village that needs a member of his profession, in which to settle down).

Comment: @chaos: I think *journeyman* has long ago lost its itinerant connotations.

Comment: @Martha: Hmm.  They're attenuated, certainly, but when they're written right into the word, I don't know that they can ever completely go away.

Comment: Seems like anyone who would be using them would not have that _journeying_ connotation, but would know what it meant. . .

Comment: The journey in journeyman has nothing to do with taking a journey of any sort; it's from French and meant one who was paid by the day. See here... http://www.thefreedictionary.com/journeyman

Comment: Shame!  "journeyperson".

Comment: This is the note Brian is referring to: "[1425–75; journeman=journee a day's work (see journey) + man man]"

Answer (score 22):

It sounds like *adept* may meet your needs.  The Hermetic Order of the Golden Dawn initiatory structure has 10 grades divided into three tiers, and the middle tier is the adept grades (5=6 *adeptus minor*, 6=5 *adeptus major*, and 7=4 *adeptus exemptus*).

Honestly, I would also be perfectly comfortable using *initiate* for your situation, not really feeling it very strongly has the beginner implications you mention.  *Adept* clearly has a much stronger connotation of competence, though.

If you were to go with this option for your middle grade, I would also suggest thinking about using *initiate* or *neophyte* rather than *apprentice* for your initial grade, to distance a bit further from the traditional guild apprentice-journeyman-master structure.  In fact, drawing a bit further from the Golden Dawn, in which the next grade up from the adept tier is 8=3 *magister templi* ("Master of the Temple"), we could get a super-sexy progression of *neophyte-adept-magister*.

Comment: I think chaos nailed it.  "Adept" is used in this context fairly commonly.  Well as commonly as people are talking about names for levels of secret knowledge, that is. (Heh).  It implies, "not a beginner, but not a master either".

Comment: +1, Journeyman is the correct middle term for the progression listed in the question, but if we're going for secret knowledge then initiate/adept/master makes more sense.

Answer (score 7):

Whenever I hear *secret knowledge*, naturally I immediately think of Freemasonry.

So, I understand there are three degrees of Craft or Blue Lodge Freemasonry (info via Wikipedia):

- Entered Apprentice – the degree of an Initiate, which makes one a Freemason;
- Fellow Craft – an intermediate degree, involved with learning;
- Master Mason

Therefore, *fellow* seems appropriate here. You may simply go with *member*.

Another word that may fit is *journeyman*. Might have problems with gender neutrality on that one, though.

Comment: *Fellow Craft* makes me go "fellow craft *what*?" It sounds incomplete, or at least incorrectly conjugated.

Comment: +1 for *Journeyman*.  In the days of craft apprenticeships, 'journeyman' was the next step in the progression.

Answer (score 6):

Just for fun, I'll throw in another word, based on the question's tag line more than on the content: **Acolyte**

Comment: This may not be my favorite term, but it's certainly a reasonable option.

Answer (score 3):

I would not go with **Journeyman** in spite of its timeless use in guilds as an expert who is not a master.  In my opinion its application is more akin to **Artisan** or **Craftsman** or someone else who, while still considered an expert, can have varying skill levels from person to person bearing this title.  Even a world class glass-blower can be considered a journeyman in my opinion.

**Adept**, I think, is a generally good middle-grade word since the subject is secret knowledge. I think there are other options available to you, provided you consider bumping *apprentice* down to something more unskilled (where fun words come in, such as **Probationer** or **Novitiate**).  However, the context is very limited; *secret knowledge* can be a little ambiguous.

If the secret knowledge pertains to a skill or technique, I'd go with **Practitioner** for your middle-grade because of the phrase *licensed practitioner* which is reminiscent of black-belt level students in a martial arts studio:  They are experts that carry some influence over the new **Initiates, Novices, Acolytes,** or **Neophytes** while still learning and answering to a **Master** or **Doyen** (I really like doyen: a combination of technical expert and leading authority, the perfect hybrid of technical prowess and extensive understanding while still maintaining the Educator status).

For secret knowledge that is intended more for understanding than application, you might [carefully] consider **Graduate** since this intermediate level of knowledge is mimicked in modern education.  Somebody who is not a novice anymore (out of college) may continue their learning and get a **Master's** degree! (coincidence?)

However, use caution in immediate context because since many people choose not to continue their education, **Graduate** has acquired a connotation of culmination or conclusion.  So when introducing **Graduate** as a tier, be sure there is clear reference to a master figure.  **Scholar** also accomplishes this, while a little weaker in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

How about **practitioner**? It is “a person actively engaged in an art, discipline, or profession” (*New Oxford American Dictionary*).

Answer (score 1):

I talked with my Boilermaker friend yesterday to prepare for this search.  He says the Boilermakers Union (NOT their full name) currently recognizes (at least informally) 5 levels:  Helper, apprentice, journeyman, foreman and instructor. They've moved away from the title master.

A helper provides the non-technical assistance needed to create a "boiler."  A helper lifts, carries, finds tools or holds parts during construction.

An apprentice is learning to perform the technical aspects of construction.  An apprentice is closely supervised, and participates in formal instruction provided by the instructors.

A journeyman has completed the apprenticeship program and is trusted to complete all aspects of construction under the considerably less focused supervision of the foreman.

For my secret knowledge/religious purpose, I'm using:  *Initiate, devotee, adept, practitioner* and *master*.

Answer (score 0):

***Expert*** is commonly used as a skill level between *apprentice* and *master*.

Also, ***disciple*** or ***mentor***.

Comment: I'd consider *expert* to be a synonym of *master*, and *mentor* implies teaching - not necessarily a feature of someone who has not yet attained mastery. *Disciple* might work, except it has religious connotations that could be confusing.

Comment: I've not heard of the religious attachment to *disciple*...I figured it wasn't anymore religious than *follower* so I think both of those would have to fall to the bottom with *trainee* or *pupil*

Comment: @Rant Disciple has a pretty strong religious context. You've heard of the disciples of Christ? Take a look at Wikipedia's disambiguation page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disciple

Comment: @Marthaª I've seen expert used as a step below master in a number of situations, including video game difficulty levels.