# More than an intermediate but less so than an expert

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a word for a person with more expertise (in certain field) than an intermediate but less so than an expert?

Comment: Related: _[Word for a person who has been initiated into secret knowledge](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/14021/5822)_.

Comment: Also related: _[What are common word sets for describing ranks in a profession?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/20025/5822)_.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Depending on the field (and potentially how close to intermediate/expert you want to be), a variety of words are viable:

- Advanced
- Seasoned
- Experienced

Answer (score 6):

[Journeyman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Journeyman)

Exactly what qualifies you to be a journeyman varies from profession to profession (if it is even used within a given profession).

It generally means someone who has completed all their training and is considered proficient without having yet proven their mastery.

Answer (score 1):

Skilled, proficient http://www.synonyms.net/synonym/expert

However I have never seen the need.

novice/beginner, intermediate, expert

are the terms normally used

Answer (score 1):

In many companies, the HR dept. have a rating scale along the line of the following:

Novice => Intermediate => **Senior** => Expert

Answer (score 0):

In Belgium you often see *medior*, which is between junior and senior.
It's redundant; if you're neither a junior X nor a senior X, then you're just an X.