# What adjective is between "intermediate" and "advanced"?

Tags: word-choice

What adjective is between "intermediate" and "advanced"?

Specifically, my academic program already has an intermediate programming course, and a proposed course does not seem to meet the standards for what I would consider advanced, so I would like to propose another term that can be used for it.

Comment: related: [More than an intermediate but less so than an expert](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20032/more-than-an-intermediate-but-less-so-than-an-expert)

Comment: In this context, I think Eugene nailed it.  Intemediate Programming I; Intermediate Programming II.

Comment: I like @EugeneSeidel's suggestion.  Could you make it an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Roman numerals to distinguish the different levels, e.g., Intermediate I, Intermediate II.

Answer (score 5):

[Intermediate](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/intermediate) is defined as the state of being between two extremes.  In the academic sense, these extremes are *beginning* and *advanced*.

> : being or occurring at the middle place, stage, or degree or between
>   extremes

Having said that, I suggest *high intermediate* or *intermediate plus*.

Comment: @combread ninja -  It would need, I think, an hypen between high and intermediate. But, and I do not understand why, also I think that this hypen is unnecessary between intermediate and plus.

Answer (score 2):

Between intermediate and advanced there is "high-intermediate".

Answer (score 2):

A few words come to mind: experienced, proficient and skilled. It's hard to distinguish what comes in between those words exactly. I usually see the progression being beginner, intermediate and advanced. But I also feel that those three alone don't make up all levels of knowledge or skill.