# Word for expressing someone whose experience is mid-level?

Tags: single-word-requests

Someone with a low level of experience in something is a *newbie* or a *rookie*.

Someone with a high level of experience is an *expert* or *specialist*.

But what do you call someone with a mid-level of experience?

Comment: Why the down votes?

Comment: See also: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/43111/noun-for-person-with-intermediate-skill and also http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/62574/what-adjective-is-between-intermediate-and-advanced and also http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20032/more-than-an-intermediate-but-less-so-than-an-expert and also http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/105325/talking-about-skills-level-which-adjective-fits-better-intermediate-or-medi

Comment: How 'bout just *experienced*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason there is often nothing for a mid-level is because the others draw attention to some unusual condition, such as being *junior* or *senior*.  If you are neither junior nor senior, then no further shading is required.

However, if you wanted to go with the old guild system, the grades would be ***apprentice***, ***journeyman***, and ***master***, terms that are still sometimes used in the crafts and trades.

---

**WARNING**: Be warned that the words you’ve chosen above are not comparable, as they are not in the same register — at all.

For example, the opposite of a *senior* member of the staff is a *junior* member, and the opposite of a *beginner* might be an *experienced* staff member.

I’m not sure what the opposite of a *“newbie”* is, since that is at best recent and **extremely casual** slang, not a “real word” you’ll find in dictionaries — and it is somewhat pejorative at that, so might be considered vulgar.  I would avoid it.  (It’s also why I’ve scare-quoted it.)

Especially on the novice end of the spectrum, you have no shortage of better words you could use instead of “newbie”, a super-casual “slangy” word which might put some people off. For people just starting out, you have words like *amateur, apprentice,
beginner, fledgling, freshman, greenhorn, initiate, junior,
learner, neophyte, new kid on the block, newcomer, novice, novitiate,
pupil, recruit, starter, student, tenderfoot,* and *trainee*.

In the realm of informal slang you do have words like *flunky, greenie,* and
*rookie*, but as a non-native speaker, **you should not use those** except in special situations under guidance of a native speaker. They are not of general use.

At the other end of the spectrum, you have words like *expert, old hand,
professional, senior,* and *veteran*.

Any competent thesaurus will uncover more of the same ilk, and in both categories.

Comment: Better these words?

Answer (score 0):

There are no hard and fast words for such things. Totally depends what field/context are you talking in and what are the popularly accepted words in that realm. For example, check this example out from the game *[ski runner](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_are_the_ranks_for_the_game_ski_runner)*.

Usually there ain't any words for the mid levels. Like a new person in the field might be referred to as rookie and the one who has been there for quiet a while and has earned his reputation that makes him stand out, he can be referred to as a pro. Others who've been around just as while or less, but don't stand out, won't be referred with any such adjective. Mostly, because there is ample of such people and hence no need to differentiate them out. Just like we have words in a race : **first** and **last**. But don't have words to describe the ones who stood in between!

And, the words you have used in the original post doesn't belong to the same group/context/category.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't sound very common, but one word I found was [*middler*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Middler). From video-game experience, I might call a mid-level person an [*intermediate*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/intermediate); in general, I think people will know what you mean when you use it, but it can be confused with a mediator or intermediary.