# Is the term "medior" to express "medium level expertise" wrong?

Tags: etymology

If I recall correctly from my high school latin studies words ending with `-ior` meant to express a property is more of something compared to others, like `superior`. So `junior` meant to be `younger`.

That's why I'm baffled with `medior`.

Since English is English and not Latin by tradition it might be a "legit" word. Since I'm not a native English speaker I don't know. So...

**Is using `medior` to describe *mid-level expertise* is right or wrong?**

Comment: As a native English speaker, I had never heard of this word. Then again, I'm an uncouth American, so what do I know? Looking it up, apparently it is business jargon, meaning what you say. It was probably formed by analogy with junior and senior, mistaking the comparative ending -ior with the agentive ending -or. Someone with more expertise should probably write this up; all I can provide is wild speculation.

Comment: It would rather depend on the expertise that you're refering to. Traditional skills like carpentry still use apprentice, journeyman and master. If, however you're refering to programmers, then "medior" seems to have begun making its way it into the language via the Dutch. Never encountered it in any other field though.

Comment: Related: [More than an intermediate but less so than an expert](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20032).

Comment: I think this is a dutch word.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A quick check has shown that 'medior' does not appear in any reputable dictionaries,  not even in ones of slang or jargon. We can conclude that it is not a widely accepted word - not a 'real' English word in any normal sense. That does not stop you using it if you think it will be understood, but most people won't be familiar. Some Latin speakers will probably understand it.

The normal word for "between junior and senior" is "intermediate".

Comment: Yes, it's reasonable to make up a word if people can guess or easily work out what it means, but I don't think that's the case here, especially when you can say "intermediate" etc.

Comment: Why use an attribute at all, if the others are comparative?

Answer (score 2):

The word medior is used in Dutch to express exactly what you mentioned. According to Encyclo.nl "Medior is used in various contexts as a name for a member of a particular middle group. For example, in job vacancies medior stands for 'member of the middle management', between the seniors (staff members) and juniors (starting employees)."

Comment: Do you have any evidence that this Dutch word is in active use in English?

Comment: @KillingTime I just ran across this on an English language posting for a tech position on LinkedIn: Tooling:


Javascript experience 
Strong Node.JS experience 
Medior+( 2 years+)
Dutch speaking https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/view/2444442195/

Comment: The article at encyclo.nl also describes the word as a neologism. Note also that this job posting would not be the first time that a Dutch word was incorrectly used in English.

Answer (score 0):

Within my ~20 years of experience, we have been using Junior, Medior, and Senior for the level of seniority within a job/role/position. It is very common at least in the IT/Software Engineering field.

Comment: This is the IT/Software Engineering field in the Netherlands?

Comment: I’ve been researching this because I encountered the term in the balkans. I find it odd that it’s being used in the IT context where one of the more important things is to remove redundancy. If there is a junior X and a senior X, X is just X, nor medior X. The word sounds… odd. Can you please confirm if this is the Netherlands you are talking about?

Comment: I am originally from Brasil and I have been living in the Netherlands for the last 5 years. At least in these 2 countries is how we call: junior, medior, and senior.